# How do I recreate this reflection in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, blending

[image]

How do I go about recreating this reflection in the eyeball, with that glowy effect? It would be really helpful as a noob if you can explain it in the most direct way. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What have you tried?  Have you looked at any photoshop tutorials?  We expect users here to at least make an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

That's an eye with typical red eye reflection caused by a light which comes to the eye just from the camera flash and reflects back from the retina. Generally people try to edit the photos to wipe off the redness. The red splash can be painted easily, if you need it and do not bother to shoot a typical hobby photo with on-camera flash.

In addition there's an overlay which contains a typical archery target and a single arrow in the middle of the target. The overlay is slightly transparent to make it look a reflection on a glossy surface which is not a 100% mirror. It should also be warped to curved because the reflecting surface is spherical.  It's easiest to make the reflection as composition - separate layers for target and arrow.

Getting the same blurriness and noise and other poor quality photo characteristics needs some experimentation, but a photo shot by using a camera in low light with high ISO setting and automatic noise reduction   turned OFF makes it. Noise and blur can, of course, be Photoshop effects applied to a high quality image.

Making this image actually needs many basic Photoshop skills like inserting new layers, selecting items, copying, scaling, distorting and adjusting their color, transparency & lightness, removing backgrounds etc...

Here's an half-way of the job example without any attempt to

- match lights
- insert warping and transparency to the target
- insert low quality photo effects
- have eylashes turned over the target (needs different eye photo and an extra layer).

[image]

The eye is copied from Wikipedia. The photo is taken unfortunately from a little wrong direction. There's no easy way to fix it perfect. The arrow and the target are screenshots from an archery equipment webshop. I hope using those images here in this way is considered fair usage. Trying to earn something needs purchased images with proper licenses or your own shots.

The next version has got geometry distortion for better (cannot get right in 2D a wrong eye photo, but better) watching direction. The target is warped to spherical and the reflection is combined to one layer + made transparent. Still no noise, blur nor darkening:

[image]